# @tailrec why does this method not compile with 'contains a recursive call not in tail position'?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

```
  @tailrec
  private def loop[V](key: String): V = {
    key match {
      case _ => loop(key)
    }
  }
```

This method doesn't compile and complains that it  'contains a recursive call not in tail position'. Can someone explain to me what's going on? This error message doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Pattern matching with only one `case _` doesn't make sense

Comment: @cchantep it's a minimization.

Comment: @cchantep just to demonstrate the issue. This method obviously doesn't make sense

Comment: how it can be used if loop never ends?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It compiles ok if the generic type is specified:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

 @tailrec
  private def loop[V](key: String): V = {
    key match {
      case _ => loop[V](key)
    }
  }
```

I think the error message is misleading in this case.

A simplified version gives a better hint on what's going on:

```
scala>  @tailrec
     |   private def loop[V](key: String): V = {
     |     loop(key)
     |   }
<console>:14: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method loop: it is called recursively with different type arguments
           loop(key)
           ^
```

Comment: You get some help with `-Ydebug -Ylog:tailcalls`. It seems to keep the last failure. Maybe it's confused by algo for pattern match, there's a code comment that says it used to run before typer for that reason.

Comment: Thanks! This is why I find the error misleading. Somehow adding the pattern match masks the error underdeath